# Calling a function from an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I'm trying to call a function by a number read from the command line. This is my code:

```
saveuser = function(user, callback) {
      //..
};

removeuser = function() {
      //..
};

finduser = function() {
      //..
};

updateuser = function() {
      //..
}

var options = {
    1: { 
        option: "Save a User",
        execute: "saveuser( newuser, finduser )"
    },
    2: { 
        option: "Remove a User",
        execute: "removeuser()"
    },
    3: { 
        option: "Find a User",
        execute: "finduser"
    },
    4: { 
        option: "Update a User",
        execute: "updateuser()"
    }
}

function read() {
    console.log("");
    console.log( " Enter your choice: ");

    stdin = process.stdin;
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    stdin.on('data', choice);
};

function choice (data) {
    data = parseInt(data);

    console.log("You entered: " + data);
    console.log("You choose to do: " + options[data]["option"]);
    options[data]["execute"];
};

read();
```

Right now nothing happens. If I put the function names not as a string in the array, they get executed immediately. I know I could handle this with a long if/elsif, but is there a way to do this with an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you remove the quotes from the function names, the reason they get executed immiediately is that you have the parenthesis included `()`. So remove quotes and the parenthesis:

The `saveuser` function is slightly more complicated because you want to pass arguments. This can be handled by using [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), or by creating an anonymous function (assuming you have `newuser` declared somewhere.

```
var options = {
    1: { 
        option: "Save a User",
        execute: saveuser.bind(null, newuser, finduser)
    },
    2: { 
        option: "Remove a User",
        execute: removeuser
    },
    3: { 
        option: "Find a User",
        execute: finduser
    },
    4: { 
        option: "Update a User",
        execute: updateuser
    }
}
```

Your final problem is in the `choice()` function, you aren't including the parenthesis to actually execute the function.

```
options[data]["execute"]();
//                      ^^------ required to execute it
```

Comment: `.bind` isn't old-browser-compatible. `function() {saveuser(newuser,finduser);}` may be preferable.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol this is Node, so isn't executed by a browser ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please see changes

```
var saveuser = function() {
     console.log('saveuser');
};

var removeuser = function() {
      console.log('removeuser');
};

var finduser = function() {
      console.log('finduser');
};

var updateuser = function() {
      console.log('updateuser');
}

var options = {
    1: { 
        option: "Save a User",
        execute: function() {
            saveuser(newuser, finduser );
        }
    },
    2: { 
        option: "Remove a User",
        execute: function () {
            removeuser();
        }
    },
    3: { 
        option: "Find a User",
        execute: function() {
            finduser();
        }
    },
    4: { 
        option: "Update a User",
        execute: function() {
            updateuser();
        }
    }
}

function read() {
    console.log("");
    console.log( " Enter your choice: ");

    stdin = process.stdin;
    stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
    stdin.on('data', choice);
};

function choice (data) {
    data = parseInt(data);

    console.log("You entered: " + data);
    console.log("You choose to do: " + options[data]["option"]);
    options[data].execute();
};

read();
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your code. Nothing happens after I enter a choice of what to do

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`eval(options[data]["execute"]);`

Comment: Is eval() as evil in javascript as it is in php?